# Do RPMs that provide multiple or complex versions for a single virtual package exist in the wild?

Tags: dependencies, rpm, rpmbuild

RPM is very flexible in what it allows you (the package builder) to specify under Provides.  It is possible to specify the same virtual package name multiple times, potentially with different versions.  It also allows you to specify a package with a version relationship besides equality.

So, while the following might be a typical Provides line for an RPM spec:

`Provides: virtual-name, virtual-version = 1.0, local-version = 1.5`

the following is also allowed:

`Provides: virtual-name, virtual-name = 1.0, virtual-name = 1.5`

or even this:

`Provides: virtual-name < 1.0, virtual-name >= 1.5`

`rpmbuild` will quite happily build those RPMs for you, which will query properly using `rpm` and can be installed as expected.  I have two questions: first, do any packages exist that actually use these sorts of complex Provides specifications?  Second, how would the RPM dependency solver interpret the third example, with < and >= versions?

Comment: Look at `postfix.spec` maybe? [This example](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/postfix.git/tree/postfix.spec?id=25f5011e85c22c915a5a2f301308e9d0890ea811) has virtual tags for `Provides: MTA smtpd smtpdaemon server(smtp)`. Doesn't look quite as complicated as you want.

Answer (score 0):

RPM does not have dependency solver. Yum/DNF has dependency solver. RPM just get list of packages to install/remove/update and check if all restriction are satisfied. If yes, then it will proceed and if no, then it will print error.

And how DNF handle that? It is just translated to tree of relation and it try to find best path in the graph, which is just mathematical problem.

Regarding the exacmple. A lots of packages use single provides (mariadb-server, httpd...), but I'm not aware of any example which will use two provides of the same name but different version. It can make sense in case you rename package and then you want to rename it back to original name. But I'm not aware of any example in real life.

Comment: Perhaps "dependency solver" is the wrong choice of words, but RPM itself has code that determines IF dependencies have been met, and it's this dependency checking code that yum/DNF's depsolvers are working to satisfy. As such, it doesn't make a difference to me what yum/DNF do, I just care about "What will RPM consider to be a satisfied requirement in this case".

Comment: Requires: virtual-name < 1.0 will be satisfied, Requires: virtual-name == 1.2 will not be and Requires: virtual-name >= 1.5 will be satisfied.